# Problem with value format for sendTransaction

Tags: javascript, transactions, ethereum, web3js, metamask

I have a problem with the transaction in MetaMask about the value format, I put the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    const sendEthButton = document.querySelector('.sendEthButton');

    sendEthButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      ethereum
        .request({
          method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
          params: [
            {
              from: ethereum.selectedAddress,
              to: '{{contractCreator}}',
              value: '0x29a2241af62c0000',
            },
          ],
        })
        .then((txHash) => console.log(txHash))
        .catch((error) => console.error);
    });

</script>
```

I have connected MetaMask correctly to the site and Ganache and also the transaction appears in the plugin when I press the button in my page, but only with this value in the code I see the correct one (3) but I don't know how is the formatting.

I have tried web3.toWei(number, 'ether') and web3.toHex(number) but it shows me strange values.

For example if I replace this value with web3.toWei(1, ether) it shows 4722.366483 in the MetaMask windows.

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me was

```
const amount = web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether');
const value = web3.utils.toHex(amount);
```

When sending `amount` as a string you will see 4722.366483 ETH in Metamask.

Sending `value` and you will see 1 ETH.